# PySide linked to the wrong python3 interpreter (no module named 'PySide')

Tags: python, linux, pyside

After installing pyside through `sudo apt-get install python3-pyside`, I am able to run pyside if I run my python script from `/usr/bin/python3` (the python that came with ubuntu), but when I try to run it from the python3 I installed from source, which is located in `/usr/local/bin/python3`, I get the error:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to link PySide to this binary as well?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to install it for the interpreter you are going to use, `/usr/local/bin/python3` knows nothing about the packages installed for  `/usr/bin/python3` , as a workaround you could add the path to your pythonpath but the best option is to use the pip that is pointing to /usr/local/bin/python3  and `pip install  PySide`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how do I know exactly which directory created by the pyside package to add to my pythonpath? I tried locate pyside but I have a ton of places where it is located. Thank you!

Comment: `import PySide;PySide.__file__`  from a /usr/bin/python3 shell, I would recommend trying the pip idea first

Comment: Forget pip, just saw they don't supply a binary for ubuntu, use the instructions here http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html just amke sure you use `/usr/local/bin/python3` to run any commands

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you - I tried to build/install pyside from the website you suggested, but the commands don't work with python3, only with python 2.7. I tried them all with python3 at first and there were many errors, but they worked fine with python2.7. I finished installing it and it still doesn't work because it was linked to python 2.7. Please help :(